# xdebug from remote server and emacs/geben

Tags: php, emacs, geben

I'm trying to debug a php script running inside apache on a remote server by using geben (0.24) on emacs (24.2.1) on a local box. xdebug connects, but the php script is not opened in a geben buffer. Instead, a comint buffer is opened, which is connected to xdebug on the remote server. I'm able to use this buffer to debug via raw dbgp commands, but not via a geben buffer. Do you know why this might be so? There is a customizable variable "geben-visit-remote-file", which is set to nil, should this be set to something? I'm quite lost...